# Droid Box working

Tags: android-sdk-2.1

I install the Android SDK in the mac, the AVD working good as android 2.1 api7. I use Droid box to testing apk, but fail, reply message

`droidbox.sh: line 3: adb: command not found`

`droidbox.sh: line 3: adb: command not found`

In my SDK platform have the adb file, and also I try to command to export `PATCH`, but still fail with this command. I put all those stuff in the desktop.

Anyone can help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

you need to export path of your android-sdk in your path. Droidbox at its page tell the following to import :

```
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/android-sdk/tools/
export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/android-sdk/platform-tools/
```